# upload to manytomany relationship symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have an object 'content' which has a manyToMany relationship with pictures (Picture model). Everything works until I persist (the images are uploaded, moved to appropriate folder, work fine). The persist command returns the following error:

Found entity of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile on association Creator\MainBundle\Entity\Content#pictures, but expecting Creator\MainBundle\Entity\Picture

I understand what the error means, it's expecting the Picture object instead of the uploaded file object. I don't understand where to go from here though, all the documentation I've read only shows how to upload a single file to a single column.

The picture model has only one field: file (string).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Content Controller code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($content, array('validation_groups'=>array('upload_'.$type)))
        ->add('picture')
        ->add('Upload '.ucfirst($type), 'submit')
        ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($request->getMethod()=='POST' && $form->isvalid())
{
    $content->uploadPicture();
    $em->persist($content);
    $em->flush();

    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Upload successful');                   
}
```

Content Model Code:

```
public function addPictures($picture)
{
    $this->pictures[] = $picture;
    return $this;
}

public function getPicture()
{
    return $this->picture;
}

public function setPicture($picture)
{
    $this->picture = $picture;
    return $this;
}

public function getPictures()
{
    return $this->pictures;
}

public function setPictures($pictures)
{
    $this->pictures = $pictures;
    return $this;
}

public function uploadPicture()
{       
    if (null === $this->getPicture()) {
        return;
    }

    $extension = $this->getPicture()->getExtension();
    if(!$extension) $extension = 'jpg';

    // unique file name
    $fname = uniqid().'.'.$extension;

    $this->getPicture()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $fname
    );

    $this->makeThumbnail($fname, $extension);
    $this->addPictures($this->getPicture());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out..

```
$picture = new Picture();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($picture)
    ->add('file')
    ->add('Upload Picture', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($request->getMethod()=='POST' && $form->isvalid())
{
  $picture->uploadFile();
  $em->persist($picture);
  $content->addPicture($entity);
  $em->persist($content);
  $em->flush();
}
```

Moved upload functions to Picture entity.. Had to also rename a couple functions in Content entity but nothing that shouldn't be obvious if someone is trying to replicate what I did.. Now it works great and inserts the relationship.